# PathStrategy with Angular and Nginx not working

Tags: angular, nginx

I have an angular app that is built inside the dist folder as `dist/register`. I am using docker and NGINX to deploy the application, now I have a docker file that looks like this.

```
# Stage 1

FROM node:18-alpine as build-step

RUN mkdir -p /app-ui

WORKDIR /app-ui

COPY package.*json /app-ui

RUN npm install

COPY . /app-ui


RUN npm run build


# Stage 2

FROM nginx:alpine

#!/bin/sh

COPY ./.nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

## Remove default nginx index page
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

# Copy from the stahg 1
COPY --from=build-step /app-ui/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 4200 80

ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

and my nginx conf looks like this.

```
worker_processes 4;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        location /appui {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /register/index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I build the docker image, my subroutes are not working, i.e the `localhost/` URL works and servers the index page of my app but as soon as I go to something like `localhost/users`, it fails and gives me 404.

Now, upon research I found that I can also use **HashLocationStrategy** and it worked as well but it changes the URL and appends a `#`, is there a way to make pathStrategy work?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: how you are navigating to `base/users` in the app? and share the routes ts file

Comment: When I say, base is basically localhost.